# java: How to make an object to List?

Tags: java

I have

```
List<String> uniqueStrings = stringSet.getElements();
CompSet<String> stringSet2 = new CompSet<>(uniqueStrings);
assert stringSet.equals(stringSet2);
```

where uniqueStrings is an List contains "a","b","c".

In class `CompSet`, I have a equals function to see if the content of object passed into the function is the same as the content of `CompSet`.

```
public List<T> getElements() {
    List<T> ele = new ArrayList();
    for (int i =0;i<NUBMER_OF_BUCKETS;i++){
        ele.addAll(storage[i]);
    }
    return ele;
}

public boolean equals(Object other){
    List<T> x = (List)other;

    return x.equals(this.getElements());
}
```

Yet when I execute the code, the following error occurs:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: hk.edu.polyu.comp.comp2021.assignment4.CompSet cannot be cast to java.util.List

Is there any idea to deal with this?

Comment: Show the class definition of CompSet

Comment: Why are you casting to a List anyway?

Comment: This makes no sense. `this.equals(other)` shouldn't be the same as `this.getElements().equals(other)`.

Comment: You should probably cast `other` to `CompSet` and use `Arrays.equals` on their `storage`.

Comment: @Dabiuteef u're right other should be cast to CompSet. I must be too sleepy to make this silly mistake.. lol

Comment: `List<T> x = (List)other;` to `CompSet x = (CompSet)other;` and it's ok

Comment: No, it's not okay, because you're not checking the type first. And because of the other point I mentioned. And you don't need to cast in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here...

```
public List<T> getElements() {
     List<T> ele = new ArrayList();
      for (int i =0;i<NUBMER_OF_BUCKETS;i++){
         ele.addAll(storage[i]);
      }
  return ele;
}
```

You have created class compSet inside you are writing method getElements() and returning java.util.List.

But some confusion is also over there in this line.

```
CompSet<String> stringSet2 = new CompSet<>(uniqueStrings);
```

Have you defined constructor for this ? but still you cannot do because uniqueString is list of string & CompSet is object of same class.